# updateToken not working (not resolving) for Conversations Javascript SDK

Tags: node.js, twilio

My goal is, upon Twilio token expiration, to update my local Conversations client with an updated token via Client.updateToken. updateToken returns a Promise and, upon resolving, you should have a client that can make authenticated requests to the Conversations service. However, updateToken's returned Promise never ends up resolving.

Please see the following gist which details and logs my observation that @twilio/conversations Client.updateToken returns a promise that never resolves: https://gist.github.com/danscan/85b188bf7a3f0a095f12937ccb2082e3

For the purpose of compressing the demonstration into a reasonable amount of time, I set the Twilio tokens to expire after 4 minutes.

The reason you see handleTokenRefresh logging about a minute after the client was created with a fresh token is because, per Twilio docs, the `tokenAboutToExpire` event is emitted when the token will expire in 3 minutes or less.

I believe this issue to be totally independent of the token expiration times I configured, and I've tested it with multiple token TTLs.

The above gist and logs show that Client.updateToken returns a promise that never resolves/rejects, and it does not update the token. How does everyone deal with this critical issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the comments in your gist, I can see that @berkus has responded to say that this seems to be a bug on the Twilio side.

While waiting for the fix, one thing you could do is to shutdown your existing client and create a new one with the updated token. This is likely a lot of work unsubscribing and re-subscribing to various events, so it may be worth just waiting for a fix.

Comment: Thanks for the response Phil! We tried that approach but it gets pretty hacky with mixed references to different clients. Will probably wait for a fix for now. Not sure how long these kinds of fixes generally take on Twilio's end. Do you know if it's days, weeks, months?

Comment: I can't say how long this will take I'm afraid. I'm not aware of the team's roadmap and priorities and would hate to promise something on their behalf. The best plan here would be to open a ticket with support which can be used to track this request and notify you when it is released.